# jQuery retrieve parameter from function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cumulative-returns').graph({
            width: 400,
            height: 180,
            graphtype: 'bar'
        });
    });
```

I have a binded a function on click to `#cumulative-returns` and I want to be able to get the `graphtype` value like..

```
$('#cumulative-returns').click(function() {
  alert(this.graphtype)
});
```

Is this possible or how else would you go about it? Maybe have some code in the graph function that stores the parameters in some global array (messy but feasable)?

*edit: here is the graph function:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.graph = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var defaults = {
                name: $(this).attr('id')
            };
            var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var img = this;
            $.post('../generate_graph.php', opts);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What plugin are you using? It depends on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.graph = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var defaults = {
                name: $(this).attr('id')
            };
            var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var img = this;

            $(this).data('graphtype', opts.graphtype); // Addition!        

            $.post('../generate_graph.php', opts);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then just do:

```
$('#cumulative-returns').click(function() {
  alert($(this).data('graphtype'));
});
```

Comment: while you're at it, add a fallback to the extend. `var opts = $.extend(defaults, options || {});`

Comment: @jAndy: jQuery does this itself.

Answer (score 0):

You do get the dom element that has been clicked stored in `this`. Then I don't know if it has the `graphtype` method linked to it, it all depends on how `.graph()` behaves.